# How to read images from pandas column in a pytorch class

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to define a pytorch dataset class that reads the absolute path from a column to pull the image. When I try this with multiple packages, I get errors.  Below are the errors for each package I'm aware of:

`Pathlib.Path`: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method`

`glob.glob`: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method`

`os.path`: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Below is my `pytorch` custom dataset.

```
class image_Dataset(Dataset):
'''
image data class    

'''
def __init__(self, data, transform = None):
    '''
    Args:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
        data = dataframe
        image = column in dataframe with absolute path to the image
        label = column in dataframe that is the target classification variable
        policy = ID variable

    '''
    self.image_frame = data
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.image_frame)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()

    label = self.image_frame.iloc[idx, 16]
    pic = Path(self.image_frame.iloc[idx,19])
    img = Image.open(pic)
    policy = self.image_frame.iloc[idx, 1]
    sample = {'image': img, 'policy': policy, 'label':label}

    if self.transform:
        image = self.transform(image)

    return image, label, policy
```

path column in my dataset values looks like the following:

`D:/Models/Photos/Train/train_img.jpg`
Full trace back below:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-261-38143c041795> in <module>
      7 
      8 for i in range(len(roof_data_test)):
----> 9     sample = roof_data_test[i]
     10 
     11     print(i, sample[0].shape, sample[1], sample[2])

<ipython-input-260-1bd25b938fea> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     25 
     26         label = self.image_frame.iloc[idx, 16]
---> 27         pic = Path(self.image_frame.iloc[idx,19])
     28         img = Image.open(pic)
     29         policy = self.image_frame.iloc[idx, 1]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2141     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   2142 
-> 2143         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2144         try:
   2145             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    221                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    222             try:
--> 223                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    224             except ValueError:
    225                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   2068             return
   2069         elif is_integer(key):
-> 2070             self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   2071         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
   2072             # a tuple should already have been caught by this point

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   2137         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2138         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2139             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: I tried running your code with a dummy dataframe of this form `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "my_path", "policy_here"]], columns=["label", "path", "policy"])` and it works (provided I change the `image` variable to `img`, since it is not defined anywhere else, and I change the indeces of the column to 0, 1, 2). Are you sure the problem is not the dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'm not sure I follow you though.  When I tested the `self.image_frame.iloc[idx,19]` with the actual data frame, it pulled the path string so my column number is correct.  I think I'm missing something in your comment though.

Comment: Can you check the `type` of the path string returned by your dataframe? The error on `Pathlib.Path` makes me think that the string you pass to the `Path` is maybe not a string at all. Also, can you post the full traceback just to be sure which line the error comes from?

Comment: full traceback added to the question.  When I do `type(data.iloc[0:1, 18:19].items)` I get back `method`.  When i do `type(data.iloc[0:1, 18:19].values)` I get back an array.  How does that happen?

Comment: `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` is telling you that your are trying to access a column that is not there. Are you sure your dataframe has 19 columns (indeces from 0 to 18)?

Comment: Annnnd that's it.  Wow.  Simple mistake.  Thank you.  If you would like to drop that in a solution, I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` is telling you that your are trying to access a column that is not there. Make sure that the columns you are trying to access exist